# Hibernate H2 database relative path

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I have an H2 database file calls "test.db". The file is located in my application
directory: "myApp/resources/test.db".
I'm not able to get this works for me.So, what's the correct way to refere to a relative path.

Here is the configuration of my hibernate.cfg.xml.

```
 <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:/test</property>
        <property name="connection.username">test</property>
        <property name="connection.password">1234</property>


        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
```

The error occurs is:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:file:/test2". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-191]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should write the URL as a explicit relative path: 
`<property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:./test</property>`